# Cardinality of two number ranges

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am studying number theory, and I have the following question:

> If $A$ is the set of all real numbers between $0$ and $1$, and $B$ is the set of all real numbers between $0$ and $2$, then which function from $A$ onto $B$ is a one-to-one function?

Choices are $f(x)=x+1$ and $f(x)=2x$. Both seem correct to me. $f(x)=x+1$ will map elements from $A$ to $B$, and so will $f(x)=2x$. But the answer is $2x$ only — no further explanation. Can someone please tell me why? Thank you.

Comment: $x+1$ maps $A$ to the set of all real numbers between $1$ and $2$, not between $0$ and $2$.

Comment: but why does that matter? the definition of cardinality is if there is a one-to-one mapping, and not that extremities of the ranges should match. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Because there is no $f^{-1}(0) \in A$ for $f(x) = x+1$

Comment: this seems more like set theory than number theory

Comment: @openspace I see it! thank you. This can be the answer.

Comment: The key is the word *onto*.

Comment: I don't like that text language and wording.  $f(x)=2x$ with domain $(0,1)$ and codomain $(0,2)$ is bijective, it is both one-to-one ($f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y$)  and onto (every element in $(0,2)$ gets mapped onto).  $f(x)=x+1$ with domain $(0,1)$ and codomain $(0,2)$ is one to one ($f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y$) but it is not onto (none of the numbers $1$ and less are mapped onto).  Now we say a function maps from the domain ***to*** the codomain. But notice the book says ***onto***. From that we are supposed to pick up the function needs to be onto. The book put it in a place easy to miss.  I don't like it.

Comment: @fleablood and Gerry Myreson very good point. So does the mapping for cardinality comparison always have to be bijective?

Comment: "So does the mapping for cardinality comparison always have to be bijective?" yesssssssss..... the *definition* of two sets having the same cardinality is that a bijection between the sets exist.... The reason I am being hesitant is that there are theorems for other ways to prove equal cardinality.  For example there can be a one-to-one function from A to B and a different function one-to-one from B to A but neither are onto.  That's okay because that's different theorem.  But the *definition*  is one bijection exists between the two.

Comment: If $f: A \to B$ is one to one but not onto then $|A| \le |B|$ for example $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb R; f(x) = \frac 12 x$ is one to one but not unto and $|\mathbb Z| < |\mathbb R|$.  If $f:A\to B$ is onto but not one to one then $|A| \ge |B|$.  For example $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb Z: f(x) =\lfloor x \rfloor$ is onto but not one-to-one and $|\mathbb R| > |\mathbb Z|$.  But if $f:A\to B$ is bijective then $|A|=|B|$. Example $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb R: f(x) = \tan(\frac \pi 2\cdot x)$ is one-to-one and onto and $|(-1,1)| = |\mathbb R|$.

Comment: Those three cases are pretty great. Thanks

Comment: the concepts of "into" and "onto" should make this fairly intuitive even the when dealing wtih "infinities" things can get 'weird" but if you can go "into' something you are "smaller" or equal.  If you can go "onto" something you are "bigger" or equal.  That *sounds* like handwaving but, surprisingly it is valid.

Comment: By the way; this problem isn’t *really* about cardinality; I mean, one of your conclusions can be used to make a statement about cardinality, but that is not really germane to the problem you are being asked to solve.